# How do I make my StringVar on tkinter brings the correct value out of an input on a CTkEntry?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, customtkinter

I'm making an project on my university and I'm having some trouble when receiving the value coming from a variable which comes from an input from a CTkEntry, from tkinter and customtkinter in python, does anyone know what did I do wrong?

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter 
import customtkinter

# System Settings ---------------------------------------------------------------------
customtkinter.set_appearance_mode("System")
customtkinter.set_default_color_theme("blue")

# App frame ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
app = customtkinter.CTk()
app.geometry("720x480")
app.title("Login to Database")

# Functions ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def faceIDValidation():
    print(wishedLevel)

#UI Elements --------------------------------------------------------------------------

text = customtkinter.CTkLabel(app, text="Insert here a number", font=customtkinter.CTkFont(size=15, weight="bold"))
text.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

wishedLevel = tkinter.StringVar()
databaseLevel = customtkinter.CTkEntry(app, placeholder_text="1, 2 or 3", width=100, textvariable=wishedLevel)
databaseLevel.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

camera = customtkinter.CTkCanvas(app)
camera.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

faceIdButton = customtkinter.CTkButton(app, text="Login", command=faceIDValidation)
faceIdButton.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

# Run app -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

app.mainloop()
```

I tried putting variable inside the function, outside, make it a global but nothing seems to work, it always comes out as "PY_VAR0"

Comment: You have to call `.get()` on the StringVar to retrieve its contents.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks a lot! Actually I tried on the StringVar but it worked actually when made on databaseLevel (the entry) and it worked!! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you're encountering with the variable displaying as `PY_VAR0` suggests that you are trying to print the StringVar object itself instead of its value. StringVar is a special variable used in Tkinter to hold string values, and when you print it directly, it will display as `PY_VAR0` or similar.

To access the value of the StringVar wishedLevel, you need to use the .get() method to retrieve the actual string value stored in the variable. Here's how you should modify your faceIDValidation function to correctly display the value:

code sample

```
def faceIDValidation():
    wished_level_value = wishedLevel.get()
    print(wished_level_value)
```